# Installing Geant4 alongside GEANT3: Question for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I intend to ask the following question:

**Can I install [Geant4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geant4) alongside [GEANT-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEANT-3) on my [Ubuntu 15.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_15.04_.28Vivid_Vervet.29) (Vivid Vervet)? I have already installed GEANT-3. How can I install Geant4 without making any problems?**

Can I ask the question on Stack Overflow? I am not even sure if I am asking the right question here.

Comment: Similar question asked on PhysicsMeta: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6909

Comment: ydoncha doit and find out?

Comment: AFAIK, Geant has a forum (or mailing list) and a living community. You should ask there, not here!

Answer (score 27):

That doesn't seem to be a [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) nor *a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*. It feels more like product support, so 
that question is not on-topic on Stack Overflow.

There are a few other sites you could check in regard to software:

- [Super User](http://superuser.com)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

but before you post visit their help-centre or ask on their meta to make sure the question is on-topic. AS your software seems to be used by  physicists you might ask for a [site-recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) on the meta of physics.se.

And asking here if something is on-topic is perfectly fine.

Comment: Is not necessary to ask it in AU, you can perfectly ask it in SU or U&L as it's perfectly on topic on those sites too.

Comment: Tnx @Braiam, updated the answer

Comment: Also, it's not "; and a •a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", rather product support.

Answer (score 9):

No.

You should instead ask [the GEANT forum](http://hypernews.slac.stanford.edu/HyperNews/geant4/cindex).

Comment: Stack Exchanges tend to be a much better place to ask and answer questions than forums. Forums are better for longer back and forths and threaded discussions, not definitive Q&A.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Yes but, and I can't believe I have to keep saying it, just because SEs are easier for solving your problem for you, that doesn't magically make every possible question ever in the universe on-topic on them. Certainly asking for an installation guide is _way_ off-topic on any SE I can think of. Sometimes you just need to go and ask the people who actually make the product. Some effort required. Stack Exchanges are better _precisely_ because they have a narrow scope and strict rules.

Comment: What question is not on-topic for them? Either there's a SE where it's already on-topic, or we need a new SE proposed.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: So we need an SE to cover every possible question in the universe now? That's absurd. Embrace the variety of life, my friend: there are different ways of procuring information. Don't try to put all your eggs in one basket. It won't work. **Stack Exchanges are Q&As** for brief, concise, precise, specific questions. Not requests for "tips" or "guides" or "walkthroughs". Ever.

Comment: Why not? We already have other, inferior types of websites for every possible question in the universe now.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: So let's just replace all other websites with Stack Exchanges and then ignore the format and purpose of SE. Okay. Good job.

Comment: As an example based on my personal experience LabView questions are **way** better to be asked on stackoverflow than on NI forums. Saves tons of nervous cells.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: That's as may be but "LabView questions" is not a specific description. It does not include the fact that (presumably) those questions were of a suitable form for an SE. The question this bloke's asking about is _not_.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: because those type of posts *don't work in this format*. We'd lose the reason why this site is successful: focusing on what works in this format, and making that work really, really well. Tips, guides and walkthroughs don't work in this format, that's what other sites are for.

Answer (score 3):

Now that is really a special case question. It's unlikely that people who are not physicists would even know what GEANT is. Normally on Physics.SE questions about software are off topic, but you might try asking on Physics.SE Meta to see if they might make an exception. At least you will encounter users there who know what GEANT is.