# Was my question really off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

After not finding a comprehensive guide anywhere, I asked (and spent a lot of time answering) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37616521/2282538) about setting up a Windows VM on a mac for hosting a SQLServer DB.  While the question doesn't contain any programming, the purpose of the question is to set up a local programming environment with access to a SQLServer DB.  It was flagged for being off topic.

The `put on hold as off topic quote says`:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming**

Does this not relate primarily to programming?  I quick search turned up a few similar questions [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149305/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-in-win7-virtual-machine-from-mac-host) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884070/connecting-to-sql-server-2008-from-a-mac) that contained no programming and were all about configuration that  did not get flagged.

I'd be happy to move it elsewhere, but I don't think it is outside the scope of SO.

Comment: I think it should be moved if necessary, but not closed.

Comment: Guys that are on crappy, abusive metered mobile internet, *don´t try to open that question*.

Comment: I think a "how to install this software step-by-step" question is too broad, personally.

Comment: Erm, wait, this is on topic only because a programmer did this instead of IT staff?  I installed Quicken Deluxe once, does that make questions about installing Quicken on topic?  Just because you wear a different hat sometimes doesn't make the hat on topic.

Comment: Off-topic for SO, on-topic for a couple of other SE sites definitely, IMO. Pretty borderline, though. I can understand confusion. Nice complete answer by the way -- don't let this situation discourage you from answering with such completeness in the future (believe me, SO needs more of that).

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298563/792066

Comment: By your logic, questions about computers that won't boot are on-topic here if it's a programmer's computer. Or a question about a problem with my monitor, keyboard or mouse because I use them when coding. There are other [se] sites to answer those sorts of question, just like there are about questions related to database administration, networking or server issues, and questions specifically related to OSes like [ubuntu.se] or [apple.se].

Comment: Your question is a very fitting question for super users but doesn't directly pertain to SO. If you'd had a connection issue in your code i would agree. But your question is directly related to setup of general purpose software many users would be using across multiple platforms for multiple uses and would likely hit the audience you are looking for. Irrespective of what your intended goal may be.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon:  What's general purpose about an SQL server running on a machine, virtual or otherwise?  The very likely scenario is that it's either a part of a deploy configuration, or it's part of a development configuration.  At the bare minimum, I see the latter expressed in the question, so I *adamantly* disagree with the assertion that this is "general purpose".

Comment: @Makoto Because It wasn't prosed as such? Also, I would trust an SA/DBA to know far more of the intricacies and configuration management of a virtual machine and SQL Server than I would a developer.  That is __no__ knock to a developer either.  In a business where we all strive to be `T shaped` would you not want to trust the `T` whose depth of knowledge was more focused around your immediate concerns. Any other questions directly relating to deploy configuration scripts is then focused on SO where you can provide working/non working code examples.

Comment: The question is poor but the answer is a good one, either way though it is still off topic on [so].

Comment: @MikeMcMahon:  That doesn't quite answer my question.  There's nothing that would make it on topic for Super User, which [explicitly lists programming](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) as something that it *doesn't* accept.  If this same question were posed there, it would be closed because it seems to pertain to development.  As for DBA, I'm not suggesting it belongs there either, since I don't participate in that community, and a [skim of what's on topic there](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would *also* suggest that they'd redirect such a question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Makoto What's programming about configuring a SQL Server on a Mac? IMHO it belongs on [su] or [sf] far more then it belongs here. What they then decide to do with it is up to those respective communities.

Answer (score 11):

> unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming

If you read the [help page,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it offers you more details:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is**
> - a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**

Now, dunno you, but are only programmers that have to install virtualbox on their macs to have access to applications they can't run natively? [Nope.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62513/30625)

BTW, that question has many more options that doesn't involve virtualization.

Comment: I agree that if I installed a Windows VM so that I could play solitaire, that would be off-topic.  But I think something that is helping me setup a local development environment is fair game.

Comment: @Tyler then how about "How can I change Notepad fonts?" or "How can I install gcc?". Once you accept ones because "is fair game" you have to accept others because "others did, so mine is fair game too". At that point it makes little sense to have a site dedicated to programmers doing programming and another to programmers doing something [that isn't programming](http://superuser.com/). Lets keep ourselves to strictly programming questions, since that's what we are actually good at.

Comment: Here is a very popular question about installing gcc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-piece-by-piece-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-libra

And here is notepad font size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723677/how-to-save-the-setting-of-font-size-in-notepad-as-default

Comment: @Tyler I said notepad, not notepad++, but that's besides the point. Are you really going to look for examples to prove your point instead of looking [at the complete cesspool of crap that fits the same category](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[debian]%20or%20[ubuntu]%20or%20[ubuntu-9.04]%20or%20[ubuntu-13.04]%20or%20[ubuntu-14.10]%20or%20[ubuntu-8.04]%20or%20[windows]%20or%20[windows-8]%20or%20[windows-7]%20or%20[windows-8.1]%20or%20[windows-xp]%20or%20[windows-10]%20is%3aq)?

Comment: @Braiam Looking at your link, while I can agree that most of that is complete crap that should never have been posted here, most of that is complete crap that should never have been posted *anywhere*, and I actually get the impression that a significant portion of it could have been cleaned up and formed appropriate questions for SO if the users posting those questions had invested just some effort instead of dumping their thoughts without regards to how they would be received or understood. That's not an argument for or against the OP here.

Comment: @hvd So you are saying that because that shouldn't be posted anywhere this is fine? Are you aware that we have a hard time moderating the crap posted here that is, albeit with some reluctance, on topic, that you want us to moderate also what definitively doesn't belong here? That's not sustainable.

Comment: @Braiam No, I'm not saying that, and in fact specifically put in a sentence to make it clear that I'm not saying that. If you're not going to bother reading comments before replying to them, there's little point in me trying to further clarify.

Comment: @hvd if you are not going to use the help center and uphold the principles that are this site is based upon, why are you expecting me to actually read your comments? Once you somehow manage to convince the rest of us that "installing X" is somehow on topic and this is written into the help center, any argument is invalid *by principle*.

Comment: It seems that you feel like the quality of the question in question is...crap, when it just isn't.  I'll put that aside for now, but I do want to address a point you're making:  "installing X" is on-topic for the site so long as it pertains to something that programmers use.  We have questions about IDEs here which developers use every day.  I see this as no different, as the developer simply wants to use a copy of SQL Server on their Mac, and they've found a good way to go about it.  If a developer's only recourse was to use an external server for it, it wouldn't be local development anymore.

Comment: @Makoto I use the Coffee machine everyday, should I ask a question here about that when it's on the fritz?

Comment: @Lankymart:  Strawmen arguments don't serve you well here.

Comment: You're absolutely right @Makoto which is why your argument holds no weight, completely behind Braiam on this one.

Comment: @Makoto Installing SQL Server on a Mac is not related to programming, it's that simple. If the question had said How do I install Windows Server 2012 on my Mac so I can do local development?, would that be on-topic? The answer to that is just the same as if they wanted to install it to play games, work in CAD or run Microsoft Office etc, the list is endless. Just because they end with *"for local development"* doesn't make it anymore relevant.

Comment: There's a difference between "installing SQL Server" and "installing GCC". SQL server is not directly related to programming but GCC is. Further, there's obviously a lot of people who don't know how to install it properly given the questions on this site (and Superuser/Unix/Askubuntu is worse, I see people giving bad advice on how to compile programs there all the time.) cont.

Comment: cont. Even the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-piece-by-piece-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-libra) demonstrates that the person ***did not read*** the "Installing GCC" link in OP's post, and gave a unnecessarily complicated answer.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I'm not sure what you are getting at? I need to install gcc to build something from source, yet that doesn't make me a programmer. You can know how to "write code" yet never built it yourself, at the same time that you can "build software" and be clueless about the underlying language. But that's besides the point. My point is that "installing X" isn't programme-y, in the sense SO wants.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the audience of developers that work on Mac would use SQLServer locally is slim, I can respect and appreciate that this sort of question would come up.

This question is *fine* here and I don't see any reason to keep it closed.

---

Since I've noticed and commented on a lot of other answers and other discussion suggesting that it belongs on a site like either DBA.SE or Super User, I've went ahead and looked at what they accept as on-topic and will offer reasons why the question can't fit there.

[Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Since the question specifically asks how to set this up for a development environment, that would disqualify it from being eligible to live on Super User.

[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **dba.se** is for those needing expert answers to advanced database-related questions concerning traditional SQL RDBMS and NoSQL
>   alternatives.
>
> **If you have a question about...**
>
> - Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore
> - Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance
> - Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including
>     stored-procedures and triggers.
> - Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence including etl, reporting, and olap
>
> **…then you're in the right place to ask your question!**
>
> **but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...**
>
> - Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
> - Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow
> - Career advice, including salary or résumé - try Patrick McKenzie's Don't call yourself a programmer

It *smells* like it could fit on DBA.SE based on the "Database Administration" configuration piece, but my concern is the finickiness of scope.  Database configuration could be related to the actual data warehouse configuration, as opposed to configuring it for local development, which is entirely in a programmer's wheelhouse.

I don't actively participate in either of these communities, and I don't wish to come across as such.  This is simply my interpretation of what each community would allow **based on their own "How to Ask" pages.**

Comment: IMO this slim audience will get more popular as Azure web services get more popular.

Comment: @Tyler id agree and also say it's our duty to be stewards of both this site and engineering in general to direct them to SU where infrastructure related questions may best be handled.

Comment: Look you pigeon hole the other two sites what makes SO any different? If anything it is general IT about configuring SQL Server via VirtualBox on a Mac. Just because that might be used by a programmer doesn't mean it belongs on SO or deserve 12 up-votes...seriously people??

Comment: "Since the question specifically asks how to set this up for a development environment, that would disqualify it from being eligible to live on Super User" - that's an extremely flawed interpretation. So the question being "for local development" makes the difference between it being on topic for SU or not? Installing a SQL Server VM for development should be on SO, but for e.g. linking the DB with MS Access it should be on SU because Access isn't programming related? The answer will be the same either way. Using the word "development" doesn't magically make a quesiton on/off-topic for SO/SU.

Answer (score -6):

The question is more appropriate to ServerFault or SuperUser than to StackOverflow.  It's really a ServerFault question but they tend to get touchy about questions that aren't about production environments.

That said, given the number of upvotes of the question and selected answer, I'd say it ought to be on topic here even though it technically isn't.

Comment: It was all going so well until the last bit.